# remove element of custom type from array in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uicollectionview

I am using a collection view to add objects to an array called collectiveSelection

When a collection view cell is selected (currentSelection), I want to test whether this object exists in the array (collectiveSelection) or not. If it does, I want to remove it (to achieve a toggle on/off effect). If it isn't in the array, I want to add it.

The items I am adding to the array are of a custom class, so this is causing me issues when trying to use .index(of:) in my check.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    currentSelection = itMachine.selection[indexPath.row]  // returns some selection of type 'Attractions'

    if collectiveSelection.contains(where: { $0 == currentSelection}){ // if selection exists in array, remove it, if it doesn't, add it

        let itemIndex = collectiveSelection.index(of: currentSelection) // error message about .index not being available for custom class Attractions

        collectiveSelection.remove(at: itemIndex)

        updateCell(having: indexPath, selected: false)

    } else { // deselect

        collectiveSelection.append(currentSelection!) 

        updateCell(having: indexPath, selected: true)
    }
}
```

I have tried making my custom class conform to Equatable, but this hasn't helped as I still get an error. Any ideas of how I can obtain the index of my custom element currentSelection within the array collectiveSelection?

Comment: you should try using the .index(where:) method and try instead of checking contains or not

Comment: It would help a lot if you posted what the error said.

Comment: You can use `filter` on the `collectiveSelection` to remove the element - just do `collectiveSelection.filter { $0 != currentSelection } ` but it sounds like your issue is with equals

Comment: Don’t use an array. Use a `Set<Attractions>`. Then you can use `contains` `insert` and `remove` as long as your `Attractions` object conforms to `Hashable`.

Answer (score 0):

You may find it much easier to track the *selected indexes* rather than tracking your custom objects. After all, you have your objects in an array to begin with.

Look at this:

```
//
//  TrackSelectedViewController.swift
//
//  Created by Don Mag on 11/16/17.
//

import UIKit

private let reuseIdentifier = "TrackingCell"

class TrackSelectedViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var theCV: UICollectionView!

    // this will maintain a list of IndexPath for selected cells
    var collectiveSelection = [IndexPath]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        theCV.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 30
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)

        // does collectiveSelection contain this indexPath?
        let idx = collectiveSelection.index(of: indexPath) ?? -1

        if idx > -1 {
            // indexPath IS in collectiveSelection
            cell.backgroundColor = .red
        } else {
            // indexPath IS NOT in collectiveSelection
            cell.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        }

        // of course, you'll configure your cell other than just setting the background color

        return cell
    }

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDelegate

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        // get a reference to the cell
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)

        // does collectiveSelection contain this indexPath?
        let idx = collectiveSelection.index(of: indexPath) ?? -1

        if idx > -1 {

            // indexPath IS in collectiveSelection
            // so remove it and set the cell to Gray
            collectiveSelection.remove(at: idx)

            cell?.backgroundColor = .lightGray

            // your code:
            // updateCell(having: indexPath, selected: true)

        } else {

            // indexPath IS NOt in collectiveSelection
            // so add it and set the cell to Red
            collectiveSelection.append(indexPath)

            cell?.backgroundColor = .red

            // your code:
            // updateCell(having: indexPath, selected: true)

        }

    }

}
```

If you create a fresh `UIViewController` and add a `UICollectionView` (and connect it to the IBOutlet and DataSource and Delegate), you can run that code as-is... it will toggle the cells between Gray and Red, depending on if they are in `collectiveSelection`